# IOS phonegap AJAX stopped working after upgrade

Tags: jquery, ios, ajax, cordova

I recently updated my IOS and xcode to the most recent versions and now all the projects that I had built no longer work. The problem I am having specifically is getting AJAX calls to work with my website for database access.

Nothing has changed on the coding side, here is an example of the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://myurl.com/subdirectory/ajax.php",
    data: {
        username: "username",
        device_id: phoneUUID
    },
    success: function(data) {
        // success

    },
    error: function(e) {
        navigator.notification.alert('failure' + JSON.stringify(e), alertDismissed, 'Attention', 'Close');
    }
});
```

And I am receiving an alert that says

```
Failure{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled my whitelist plugin, re-created my entire project and manually moved over all the code, started with a brand new project from scratch with just a simple AJAX call, made sure my `<allow-navigation href="http://myurl.com/" /> <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" /> <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />` and `<access origin="*" />` are set in the config.xml, and modified my meta Content-Security-Policy.

When I modify the CSP with anything other than

`default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">`

The javascript stops working entirely. I have tried examples from answers that people have given in similar issues and I haven't came across a solution that is relevant to the recent changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by tweaking the content security policy tag.

I replaced the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap:..."` with `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: gap:..."` and that did the trick.

For some reason older content examples and formatting was not working properly.